# Scale floating divs not relative to their parent without position:absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]
I got dis:

".each_one" is every single little div displayed except for the "category_container" which is the one that is parent of all "each_one" divs.

I want to scale each_ones using percentages relatively to the height of the screen, yet i want to make the category_container div only scale to successfully contain all each_ones (like it does right now)

In other words, i just wanna make each child div somewhat bigger in height.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a fixed height (e.g. `height: 600px`) for the `.category_container` or absolute positioning:

```
.category_container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Note that in this case the parent element has to be the `<body>` element or itself fit the whole screen height.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nb4JZ/1/.

Comment: both options which i wanted to avoid, yes, but thanks for answering